# Multiple foreign key for 'extra data' table

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

i have a logical question for optimization tables relation in MySQL (and even other DBMS).
there are many table with different columns and structures in my database. for a specific reason, i need to create a new table, names `"extra_data"` with there columns `(id, table, content)`. each table (even `"extra_data"` itself) MAY needs to store extra data for undefined columns. so this extra data that is **a PHP array or object**, first **serialized** and then transform to **Base64** code and inserted to `"eaxtra_data"` table `content` column. `id` and `table name` of target table row, stored in `id` and `table` columns in `"extra_data"` too.

for example if there is two tables names "users" and "posts" and each of them need to store extra data in `"extra_data"` table:

```
"users" table:
id   name   gender   ...
1    Tom    Male     ...
2    Mary   Female   ...
3    Jack   Male     ...
...
```

```
"posts" table:
id   title    date        ...
1    news     4/11/2014   ...
2    article  4/51/2014   ...
...
```

```
"extra_data" table:
id   table   content
1    users   #$!^...
2    users   #$!^...
2    posts   #$!^...
...
```

`id` and `table` is **primary key** in `"extra_data"` table. so problem is when target row (form example row `2` in `users`) has been changed or removed, related row in `"extra_data"` must updated automatically if it's necessary. but the way to set **foreign key** in many table and in two columns (`id`, `table`) together, is imprecise to me! thanx for any help

Answer (score 1):

DarkMaze,

I see where you come from with this "extra_data" table. I don't agree, though. Once it goes against the principles of database normalization and this logic is not clear on a design perspective. I'd rather serialize whatever data you want to add to extra_data content column and save it into its respective table.

Back on the question, the only solution I see so far is to add triggers on every table related to "extra_data" in order to add/remove/update records. Which is not very productive.

Cheers,

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: thanx for your ideas, i know the importance of DB normalization and not going to break the rules. actually this extra data rarely used and will not used for every table and each rows. the goal of this table is dumping data for collecting logs and will be removed after couple of days

Comment: In this case, I don't know why you care of keeping this log data "automatically updated" as you've asked in your question.